# Problem with DC motor, GND and metallic parts (and yes/no PE)

Tags: pwm, ground, earth

I built an actuator where noise, presumably, gives me problems.

The hardware is: a 230->24 volt transformer which
feeds an electronic board which drives a DC motor (via 16 kHz PWM) and other small devices (a 7 LED display, a couple of photocells, an encoder and so on). The motor is mounted on a relatively bulky gear and the motor outer body is also electrically connected to the gear.

[image: Block diagram]

The entire board and photocells ARE ISOLATED from the rest, i.e. there is no connection between GND and the metallic parts above, and PE (protective ground) does not even enter the board. The dashed lines show the optional connections which would be absent.

The photocell is powered by the board, and seems very sensitive to noise. It works normally when the motor is off but when the motor moves, the photocell stops working. It doesn't matter whether the metallic bodies are connected or not to the mains earth. BUT, if I connect the board GND to the metallic body, the photocell works again. And again, it doesn't matter whether the metallic parts are connected to the mains earth or not.

What I don't understand is: there is only one low voltage circuit involved; when it is floating the photocell fails - but when I connect GND to the metallic gear, the whole apparatus is still floating exactly like before, but this does make the difference. What am I missing?

Please note: when I say that the photocell fails, I don't mean that the board misinterprets its input; I mean that the relay of the photocell stays excited even when it should not. A different model of photocell works well, but I want to clarify this problem because the photocell that I want to use is perfectly fine with everything else (including setups identical to this one: the low voltage circuit is always floating); only this actuator gives problems, and only when the GND (-24Vdc) is disconnected from the metal mass. The only thing I can think of, is that some noise comes in from the power supply, but I don't see a clear reason for that or, better, I don't see why attaching an electrically floating mass of metal to GND should change anything.

I am seeking for information and hints; what should I measure or investigate, perhaps using a scope?

Comment: Please provide a schematic of your system.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson TY for your interest; I've updated the question and remain at your disposal for more info if needed. PS: I tend to exclude cabling coupling between motor and photocell, they are quite apart.

Comment: That's a block diagram, not a schematic. You're getting noise so we're going to have to go to component level and, possibly, layout.

Comment: @Transistor problem is I don't have the schematic... I hope to get hints on what to try: measure, filter, don't know. Can somebody explain what happens when I connect GND to the gear mass? That solves, but I don't understand why. May be that connecting the motor chassis to GND turns the motor chassis into a shield? If so, why doesn't it help to connect the chassis to earth?